# How to modify the default execution order of sql script in liquibase?

Tags: database, oracle, migration, liquibase

I am trying to run a bunch of sql script in the Liquibase. But, be default, liquibase executes all the scripts in the order they are placed in the directory. Is there any way by which I can alter the execution default execution of these scripts i..e, execute by create table script first and then all the insert script.

My master changelog file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <includeAll path="../migration/" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I am placing all the sql script in migration folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the execution order. The only thing you can do is to change the order of files in your `/migration` directory by renaming them.

As far as I know, Liquibase sorts files in alphabetical order.

And inside the files Liquibase executes changeSets one by one from top to bottom.

**OR**

You can use `<include>` instead of `<includeAll>`. This way you'd be able to include changeLog files in the order you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                      http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <include file="../migration/changeLog_3.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="../migration/changeLog_1.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
    <include file="../migration/changeLog_2.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Good answer! When people use the <includeAll> tag, they should define a naming scheme for their sql files. I have used something like:
`00010_some_description.sql` and then `00020_next_migration.sql`. 
This was recently covered in the Liquibase blog: https://www.liquibase.org/2020/01/plain-SQL.html